# Which Version of Ubuntu is arm build?

Tags: versions, arm, system-requirements, embedded-system

I'm considering to use Ubuntu for a platform of our company's development effort of the main control unit in our country's national road VMS(Variable Message Sign) system.
In relation to that, I want to know the embedded version of Ubuntu.
Our minimum system requirements are as follows:
- 32bit processor
- 400MHz+
- SSD Size: 16GB+
- OS: Windows embedded XP or better
Thank you very much, in advance.
-- JB

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking but it looks like you should read this: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/EmbeddedUbuntu

Comment: This will be more up to date: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM @LnxSlck ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Beaglebone Black](http://www.beagleboard.org/) which is an open source HW running Angstrom. You can also run Android on Beaglebone Black. It is a TI sitara ARM Cortex A8 Application processor. (BTW I believe Angstrom and Yocto project have merged)

Also Freescale and other vendors have ported Linux to ARM Cortex A8 processor.

Atmel has ported Android to an ARM Cortex A5 processor (SAMA5D3).

Since Ubuntu is built for desktop and server applications you might have to over come some  challenges to get Ubuntu working for Embedded applications. I have seen Ubuntu running on a ARM Cortex A8, but I am not sure if it is a preferred choice.

BTW Raspberry PI is very popular in Europe.

Hopefully this will get you started.

Like to hear from to community on this topic.

**References**

- [Ubuntu Server for ARM](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server/arm)
- [Beaglebone Black](http://www.beagleboard.org/)
- [Raspberry pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/)